# Tab Index for two different Sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using "accordion" of jquery for First, Second and Third tabs. When I am clicking on TAB button, the focus first comes to Name1 and then Age1 and then Place1 and then to the button "Click here". But after Place1, I want the focus to go to the *Second* section Name2 field. How to achieve this using jquery? Please help. There is a clear image of this, but i am not able to upload it.

***Note***: Here Name1, Age1, Place1 are the fields of  *First* Section. Similarly Name2, Age2, Place2 are the fields of *Second* Section.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you upload a fiddle of the problem perhaps? Or more complete code. Also is there a reason why you're using ui accordions to simulate tab functionality and not simply using tabs? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably give this a try:
use `activate()`

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        $("#secondSection input:text").first().focus();
    }
});
```

[**Js Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxbax/10/)

Hope this will help!

Comment: No, its not working. The focus is still going to the button. The second section tab is not opening @ all. :(

Comment: @CoolGurl here it is dhavalmarthak.dm@gmail.com